# Its possible to Group by data instead of column?

Tags: oracle, group-by, oracle10g

I was thinking, if it was possible to use **GROUP BY** based on the data of a certaint column in a expecific way, instead of the column. So my question is can i create groups based on the 0 occurence of a certant field.

```
       DIA        MES       YEAR      TODAY   TOMORROW   ANALYSIS      LIMIT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        19          9       2016        111        988          0        150 
        20          9       2016        988        853        853        150 
        21          9       2016        853        895        895        150 
        22          9       2016        895        776        776        150 
        23          9       2016        776        954          0        150 
        26          9       2016        954        968        968        150 
        27          9       2016        968        810        810        150 
        28          9       2016        810        937        937        150 
        29          9       2016        937        769        769        150 
        30          9       2016        769       1020          0        150 
         3         10       2016       1020        923        923        150 
         4         10       2016        923         32         32        150
```

Like, in this case, i would want to create groups, like this:

- Group 1 (Analysis): 0
- Group 2(Analysis): 853, 895,776,0
- Group 3(Analysis): 968,810,937,169,0
- ...

Comment: So add a column and sequence it as you insert values into the table - there's your new group by.

Comment: intersting, i think it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table name is `tbl`, something like this should work (it's called "start-of-group" method if you want to Google it):

```
select 
from   ( select tbl.*,
                count(case when analysis = 0 then 1 end) 
                           over (order by year, mes, dia) as cnt
         from   tbl
       )
where  ...
GROUP BY cnt
;
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted